# Can I use JSON_EXTRACT in a Domo SQL DataFlow

Tags: domo

Domo calls one of the DataFlow types a "MySQL DataFlow". MySQL has a function called JSON_EXTRACT. How can I use this on a field that contains some JSON encoded data? I receive back the error:

> The database reported a syntax error. FUNCTION json_extract does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a somewhat old question, but I think the answer is that Domo uses an older version of MySQL (5.6) that does not support the `JSON_EXTRACT` function (5.7 and later).

You can check the version by running this statement in a MySQL DataFlow transformation step:

`SELECT VERSION();`

When I run that on the Domo instance I use at work I see `5.6.28-76.1-56`

If you go to the [JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) page of the MySQL documentation and try to select any version before 5.7 from the dropdown in the upper right of the page you will see a message saying "The page you are viewing does not exist in version X.X"